# I can't delete a file in my datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, error-handling, delete-file

I'm using this code:

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Delete This Record?", "Confirm Action", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Dim sqldelete As String
        sqldelete = "DELETE * FROM [product info] WHERE Barcode='" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString & "'"
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqldelete, strcon)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("[product info]")
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        RefreshDGV()
    End If
```

When I select an item I want to delete in my datagridview it shows an error saying:

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."

I'm not familiar with this error because my delete button codes used to work before.

Comment: Why have you used code behind to handle this?  If you set up the `DataGridView` properly you can simply put all of your SQL into the control and let it handle the deletions for you...

Comment: It was advised to us that we use codes for deleting and not the controls that came with the datagridview

Comment: You may test by `msgbox(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString)` .. is there any value ?

Comment: Thank you @matzone there was an error in that line. It should be
qldelete = "DELETE * FROM [product info] WHERE [Barcode]='" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString & "'"

i added the braces in the word Barcode

Comment: What database are you using?  `DELETE * FROM...` is not normal, should this be `DELETE FROM...`? Also, please post the return from `DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString`. This is IMPORTANT information.